spring resttemplate call throwing unauthorized error
i need to call service admin app to app with http. both the services is listening on port
c053b74b7e3a   app-pre_prod:latest      "java -jar -Dspring.…"   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp                                  appPreProd
77d20ec0905c   adminapp-pre_prod:latest      "java -jar -Dspring.…"   0.0.0.0:8980->9080/tcp, :::9080->9080/tcp                                  adminappPreProd
i am calling appPreProd from adminapppreprod with below code...
    String tenantId = Long.toString(productUserMO.getId());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add(Constants.X_TENANTID, tenantId);
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(map, headers);
    restTemplate().exchange(apiURI.concat("/addPackageTypesForProductOwner"), HttpMethod.GET, entity,
            String.class);

but getting error while making rest call

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized:
401 : "Unauthorized access"

my services are not https enabled and also my api doesnot required any authorization and been exempted from that. also call is not reaching appPreprod from adminpreprod, the issue is at calling service.. not sure what is missing in this code..
i tried changing the headers but that doesnt work either

is there any proxy or something in between?

i fixed after changing my resttemplate bean into
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
 
    return builder
        .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
        .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
        .build();
}

before i was using
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

